# Deleting and Inserting at the same time

Tags: java, postgresql

```java
public int insertMiles(UUID id, Miles miles) {

        String sql = "" +
                " DELETE FROM account_type " +
                " WHERE person_Id = ?" +

                " INSERT INTO account_type (" +
                " acc_id, " +
                " person_Id, " +
                " created_at, " +
                " acc_miles) " +
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        int totalMiles = miles.getMiles();
        totalMiles = totalMiles + miles.getMiles();
        return jdbcTemplate.update(
                sql,
                miles.getPersonID(),
                id,
                miles.getPersonID(),
                miles.getCreated_date(),
                totalMiles
        );
```

I want to delete a value specific to its id and then insert the new value after adding the two together, basically a new update of the value. Please help, this is the query I got but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: "*basically a new update of the value.*" - why not use `UPDATE` then?

Comment: You basically have a big syntax error, because you're trying to mash two statements together as a single statement. The JDBC API is designed to execute individual statements, and even drivers that support executing multiple statements at once, at minimum require you to separate those statements with a terminator character (usually `;`).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `UPDATE` to perform the action that you want?

Anyways if you want to continue with the same logic as above...

I would suggest separating your query in 2. It's cleaner and more understandable.

Example:

```java
public int insertMiles(UUID id, Miles miles) {

    String deleteQuery = " DELETE FROM account_type " +
            " WHERE person_Id = ?";

    String insertQuery = " INSERT INTO account_type (" +
            " acc_id, " +
            " person_Id, " +
            " created_at, " +
            " acc_miles) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    
    int totalMiles = miles.getMiles();
    totalMiles = totalMiles + miles.getMiles();
    
    int deleted = jdbcTemplate.update(deleteQuery, miles.getPersonID());
    int inserted = jdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery, id, miles.getPersonID(), miles.getCreated_date(), totalMiles );
    
    
    // RETURN ONE OF THEM
    return deleted;
    return inserted; 
}
```

You could also separate your queries with a `;` and try doing the update again. But I doubt that that would work.

Comment: Out of curiosity which one worked?
Did adding `;` work or the other way?

Comment: I just used your code example and it worked perfectly

Comment: But i see if you enter a new value it is 2X the value for instance if i enter 200 it shows as 400 but editing an existing value then its fine

Comment: It actually times the vale by 2 and not adding to the previous value